# Error de redirrecion en wordpress de http a https

Tags: wordpress, http

Tengo una pagina en wordpress que tiene un button en el cual te redirecciona a un link http pero no se porque motivo le agrega una s (https)y me dirije a otra pagina nada que ver;
Como puedo solucinar este problema??

Comment: Hola. Aclara tu problema. ¿Es una redirección al propio dominio o es externa? Si es al propio dominio, ¿ese dominio está en `http` o en `https`?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Pon la página en cuestión y le damos una revisada...